# Atmega32U4 USB Device/HOST mode

Tags: atmega, usb-drive

Recently I have been studying the m32u4 usb. It has USBCON register, but no HOST bit which is used to change HOST/Device Mode. I want to know how i can convert the usb from device mode to host mode. 
Could somone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Atmega32U4 doesn't support USB host mode. In order to acheive that you might need some other board or perhaps a seperate USB host IC.

Comment: Thank you. What puzzles me is that Arduino Yun can use a keyboard.